# Referencing a table in R markdown with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

It's possible to reference a figure in **knitr** like that:

````
```{r myfig}
plot(1,1)
```
````

Figure `\ref{fig:myfig}` shows ...

The same is not possible for tables, e.g.

````
```{r my_table, results='markup', fig.cap='capture'}
tab <- read.table('my_table.txt', sep = '\t')
kable(tab, 
      format='pandoc', 
      digits = 3, 
      caption =
      "Description")
```
````

Table `\ref{table:my_table}` shows ...

doesn't work! Is it possible to make this work without digging into latex? If no, what would I have to do to make it work?

Comment: This will take a while to read, but it may be worth it since you are likely to have more questions like this one in the future: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `format='pandoc'` you need to enter the \label command in the caption.

With `format='latex'` the reference is automatically created as `tab:chunk_label`.  For example,

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document
tables: true
---

```{r results='markup'}
tab <- head(iris)
knitr::kable(tab, 
  format='pandoc', 
  digits = 3, 
  caption = "Pandoc table\\label{tab:pandoc_table}"
  )
```

```{r latex_table, results='markup'}
tab <- head(iris)
knitr::kable(tab, 
  format='latex', 
  digits = 3, 
  caption = "LaTeX table",
  booktabs = TRUE
  )
```

Table \ref{tab:pandoc_table} was done using Pandoc,
while Table \ref{tab:latex_table} used \LaTeX.
````

Answer (score 0):

Replace table with tab `\@ref(tab:my_table)`